# Require XML element in XSD when another element has certain value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I need a required attribute or element only if a specific value of an enumeration is chosen. Example below:

```
  <xs:element name="TYPE" type="TestEnum" />
   <!-- // This Element should only required when TYPE = INTERNATIONAL -->
   <xs:element name="IBAN"/>

 </xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="TestEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration  value="NATIONAL"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="INTERNATIONAL"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Aside from some structural issues with your XSD fragment, the type of the constraint you request typically requires XSD 1.1's conditional type assignment or assertion constructs.  Is XSD 1.1 an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it is an Option for me. How does this constraint look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### XSD 1.1

Here's how use `xs:assert` to make `IBAN` be mandatory when `TYPE = 'INTERNATIONAL'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TYPE" type="TestEnum" />
        <!-- // This Element should only required when TYPE = INTERNATIONAL -->
        <xs:element name="IBAN" minOccurs="0"/>        
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="not(TYPE = 'INTERNATIONAL') or IBAN"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="TestEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration  value="NATIONAL"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="INTERNATIONAL"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hey there... I like that and it works. Time to get into Schema 1.1!  Trank you very much...