# XSD assert based on an element make the other complex element child optional

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

How can we got the child minOccur be defined on the basis of other element with the parent. For eg.

The **flagExist** if **true** then the **ComplexTypeObject** child element can be optional. If the **flagExist** is **false** then the child element **ComplexTypeObject** of has to be mandatory.

```
<xs:group name="GroupObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="flagExist" type="xs:boolean"/>                                                
        <xs:element name="ComplexTypeObject" type="foo:ComplexTypeObject" minOccurs="0"/>       
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<xs:complexType name="ComplexTypeObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="One" type="xs:boolean"/>                          
        <xs:element name="Two" type="xs:string"/>                   
        <xs:element name="Three" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It is slightly different from the one asked in the already existing question([Require XML element in XSD when another element has certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071177/require-xml-element-in-xsd-when-another-element-has-certain-value)). In this case the elements in the ComplexTypeObject.One ComplexTypeObject.two ComplexTypeObject.Three has to be made optional, depending on the true/false value of flagExist